# Does amsmath provide any medium to auto-break equations?

Tags: equations, line-breaking, amsmath, breqn

I'm writing large equations in texlive with amsmath, and I want them to be automatically broken at the end of the line. Is there any way to do that with amsmath?

What would you recommend me to do that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Amsmath do not provide this functionality.

It is not easy to achieve automatic line breaking of equations. The [breqn](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/breqn) package tries to tackle this problem and generally does a good job.

Comment: +1 breqn. It's compatible with amsmath, so there's little to no barrier to trying it out.

Answer (score 3):

The [autobreak](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/autobreak) package was released recently. It is less sophisticated than breqn, e.g. it requires you to place newlines on possible breakpoints. However, according to my experience, it has less clashes with other packages.