# Equation too long

Tags: equations

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I split an equation over two lines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3782/how-can-i-split-an-equation-over-two-lines)

I have a long equation,

```
$\operatorname{E} (Z_{n+1} - Z_n | X_1,..., X_n)
= \operatorname{E} (S_{n+1}^2 - (n+1) \sigma^2 - S_n^2 + n \sigma^2  | X_1,..., X_n)
= \operatorname{E} (S_{n+1}^2 - S_n^2 - (n+1) \sigma^2 + n \sigma^2  | X_1,..., X_n)
= \operatorname{E} (X_{n+1}(X_{n+1} + 2\sum_{i=1}^n X_i) - \sigma^2 | X_1,..., X_n)
= \operatorname{E} (X_{n+1}X_{n+1}) + 2\operatorname{E} (X_{n+1}) \sum_{i=1}^n X_i - \sigma^2
= \sigma^2  - \sigma^2 =0
$.
```

which I think causes warning:

> Overfull \hbox (3.16257pt too wide)

Is there some way automatically line-break long equations? Or must I specify where to line-break? Thanks!

Comment: I think your question is answered [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4240/1235) and [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3782/86) (possible duplicates).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify linebreaking manually, as per `Harald Hanche-Olsen`'s example. In some cases, `breqn` package can automatically break your lines (`breqn` is part of the `MH bundle`, see [documentation on ctan](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mh/breqn.pdf)).

Minimal example is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{breqn}
\begin{document}
\begin{dmath*}
\operatorname{E} (Z_{n+1} - Z_n | X_1,..., X_n) 
    = \operatorname{E} (S_{n+1}^2 - (n+1) \sigma^2 - S_n^2 + n \sigma^2  | X_1,..., X_n) 
    = \operatorname{E} (S_{n+1}^2 - S_n^2 - (n+1) \sigma^2 + n \sigma^2  | X_1,..., X_n) 
    = \operatorname{E} (X_{n+1}(X_{n+1} + 2\sum_{i=1}^n X_i) - \sigma^2 | X_1,..., X_n) 
    = \operatorname{E} (X_{n+1}X_{n+1}) + 2\operatorname{E} (X_{n+1}) \sum_{i=1}^n X_i - \sigma^2 
    = \sigma^2  - \sigma^2 =0
\end{dmath*}
\end{document}
```

It will not be much help for your specific example. Example of output:
[image: breqn automatic linebreaking]

As you can see, `breqn` did a good job with binary symbol `+`, but was not helpful with equal signs. That is in line with what `Harald Hanche-Olsen` said.

Comment: Thanks! Example of using breqn in my case please?

Comment: I expanded my answer in response to your question. It seems that `Harald Hanche-Olsen` already answered your question. Still, a reference to `breqn` might be helpful generally if not in this particular case.

Comment: That breqn output is strange; I thought it should have wanted to split the equation by the equals signs. The algorithm isn't perfect yet!

Answer (score 4):

Equations can be broken at relation symbols and binary operators, so long as they are not enclosed in braces. In this case, however, I think it's better to use a displayed equation with line breaks of your own choosing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{E} (Z_{n+1} - Z_n | X_1,..., X_n)
&= \operatorname{E} (S_{n+1}^2 - (n+1) \sigma^2 - S_n^2 + n \sigma^2 | X_1,..., X_n) \\
&= \operatorname{E} (S_{n+1}^2 - S_n^2 - (n+1) \sigma^2 + n \sigma^2 | X_1,..., X_n) \\
&= \operatorname{E} (X_{n+1}(X_{n+1} + 2\sum_{i=1}^n X_i) - \sigma^2 | X_1,..., X_n) \\
&= \operatorname{E} (X_{n+1}X_{n+1})
   + 2\operatorname{E} (X_{n+1}) \sum_{i=1}^n X_i - \sigma^2 \\
&= \sigma^2  - \sigma^2 =0.
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Running `texdoc amsldoc` on your system should give you more information on using the `amsmath` package.

Comment: Thanks! By "Equations can be broken at relation symbols and binary operators", do you mean automatically or manually? Could you give an xxample of using a displayed equation with line breaks?

Comment: @Tim: I expanded my answer in response to your second question. As to the first, I mean automatically. You can put a manual linebreak anywhere you like.