# How to break long expressions automatically in displaymode?

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking, tex-core, breqn

Whenever an expression is too long, it will be broken automatically in inline mode but done nothing in displaymode

E.g.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\begin{document}

$1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+0$

\[1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+0+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+0\]

 \end{document}
```

The upper one will be broken whereas the lower one not.

So how to make auto break also works in displaymode?

Comment: The package `breqn` breaks automatically. However the normally you have to break manually.

Comment: Check the [tag:breqn] tag here on tex.se for more information.

Comment: This has been asked before: [Equation too long](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11411), see also [How can I split an equation over two lines](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3782) and [Does amsmath provide any medium to auto-break equations?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4240)

Comment: I tried breqn and multline and split, but they all return errors...